# Rails 4 Validation: where to put the allow_nil when doing an inclusion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, inclusion

Are these two implementations functionally equivalent? If so, which is "better?"

```
  # from a model
  WIDGET_COLORS = %w(red yellow green)
  validates :widget_color,
           inclusion: {in: WIDGET_COLORS, allow_nil: true}
```

or

```
  # from a model
  WIDGET_COLORS = %w(red yellow green)
  validates :widget_color,
           inclusion: {in: WIDGET_COLORS},
           allow_nil: true
```

UPDATE: fixed typo so example reads *validates*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly `validate` and `validates` are different methods - it should be `validates` here.

`validates` will search the supplied hash for so-called `_validates_default_keys`, which is an internal array `[:if, :unless, :on, :allow_blank, :allow_nil , :strict]`. All the arguments passed to `validates` being in this array are treated as common options for all the validators attached to the model with this method. So if you do:

```
validates :widget_color,
          inclusion: {in: WIDGET_COLORS},
          uniqueness: true,
          allow_nil: true
```

`allow_nil` will affect both of the validators, or is equivalent of:

```
validates :widget_color,
          inclusion: {in: WIDGET_COLORS, allow_nil: true},
          uniqueness: {allow_nil: true}
```

On the other hand with

```
validates :widget_color,
          inclusion: {in: WIDGET_COLORS, allow_nil: true},
          uniqueness: true
```

it will only affect the validator it is defined for (in this case `InclusionValidator`)